# iOS 8 UINavigationBar overlaps StatusBar

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I have a view (contentView) in my MainController, witch contents a view of another UINavigationViewController (mainNavigationController). Perfectly fit screen (see image 1).

Then i wrote a function to change view of contentView to view of another UINavigationViewController:

```
func moveToNC(NCName:String) {

    let incomingViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())

    addChildViewController(incomingViewController)

    incomingViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.bounds.width, containerView.bounds.height)
    containerView.addSubview(incomingViewController.view)

    mainNavigationController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    mainNavigationController.removeFromParentViewController()

    incomingViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

NavigationBar of incomingNavigationController becomes smaller (see image 2) :(
I think because of StatusBar.

Solution with UIBarPositioningDelegate does not help :(

Thanks for help!

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that i change view, when it was scaled. (see image 3). First i should remove scale and then change view.

[image]